# Creating a PySpark map from DataFrame columns and applying to another DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently ran into an issue where I wanted to map over a number of columns of one DataFrame with  the columns of another DataFrame - essentially a look-up table allowing me to replace one set of IDs with another. This can be done trivially with a number of `joins`, matching the number of columns I wish to map over. In `Scala Spark`, this could be achieved with `Map`. Can something similar be done in `PySpark`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by leveraging

- `pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.struct`
- `crossJoin`

In the following order:

```py
# original_and_new_df is a 2 column table containing rows original_id, new_id
# input_df is a table containg colums with original_ids, 
# such as f.col(id_col_1), f.col(id_col_2)

input_df_with_mapping_col = input_df.crossJoin(
    original_and_new_df.select(
        f.map_from_entries(
            f.collect_list(
                f.struct(f.col(original_id), f.col(new_id)))
        ).alias(mapping_column_name)
    )
)

# apply the mappings 
input_df_with_mapping_col.select(
    f.col(mapping_column_name)[f.col(id_col_1)].alias(id_col_1),
    f.col(mapping_column_name)[f.col(id_col_2)].alias(id_col_2),
)
```